# How do I make a query hook return type depend on parameter type using RTK query and typescript?

Tags: typescript, rtk-query

I'm making a program using React for the UI development. The program is meant to access the file system for settings so I run some server code in node and use RTK query to do the communication with that code.

Some of the server code reads a value from an xml file. I have these interfaces defined in the server code that define the type of the request and response parameters:

```
// define the key and value pairing for the file
export interface PersistentFileValues {
  initialValue: number;
  repaymentChanges: DatedValue[];
}

// queries should provide a key that matches the pairing
export interface GetPersistentFileValueRequestQuery {
  itemKey: keyof PersistentFileValues;
}

// define type that gets the value type given a key
export type PersistentFileValue<T extends keyof PersistentFileValues> =
  PersistentFileValues[T];

// make GetPersistentFileValueResponseBody depend on GetPersistentFileValueRequestQuery
export interface GetPersistentFileValueResponseBody<
  T extends GetPersistentFileValueRequestQuery
> {
  value: PersistentFileValue<T['itemKey']>;
}
```

If I use createApi, and have an endpoint called getPersistentFileValue, how do I do the typing so that the hooks figure out the return type based on the key provided as an argument?

Currently I have:

```
endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getPersistentFileValue: builder.query<
      PersistentFileValue<keyof PersistentFileValues>,
      GetPersistentFileValueRequestQuery
    >({
      query: (queryData) => {
        return {
          url: constructGetPersistentFileValueUrl(queryData), // appends the data as a string to the url
          method: 'get',
        };
      },
      transformResponse: (result, _meta, arg) => {
        const out = result as GetPersistentFileValueResponseBody<typeof arg>;
        return out.value;
      },
    }),
...
```

There don't seem to be any type errors. However, when I use the hook:

```
const { data: repaymentChanges } = useGetPersistentFileValueQuery({
  itemKey: 'repaymentChanges',
});
```

I find that the type of repaymentChanges is too generic and I get an error if I try to get the length property.

How can I type things so that the hooks give me access to the data with the right type? Is there a better way to do this?

Before this I was making an endpoint for each value accessed from the file, but that seems pretty clunky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As RTK Query is mapping types internally to create those new function signatures, any kind of generics/overloads will be getting lost. Your best bet is taking the RTK Query-generated hook, wrapping it in your own function and providing overloads for that.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I've tried making the following wrapping function, which I put at the end of the file with createApi:

`export function useGetPersistentFileValueQueryWithReturnType<
  T extends GetPersistentFileValueRequestQuery
>(queryData: T): PersistentFileValue<T['itemKey']> | undefined {
 const { data } = useGetPersistentFileValueQuery(queryData);
return data;
}`

Now I've got a type error `Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'number & DatedValue[]'` on the `return data` line. I guess this is a typescript problem, but I don't suppose you know how I can resolve that?

Comment: I'd say the usual: if you know better than TypeScript, cast it to what you want ;)

Comment: Changed that to `return data as PersistentFileValue<T['itemKey']>` and it works as desired. Thanks!

Comment: @phry How can I correctly type the options that can be passed into the query hook? That is receive the options in the wrapper and then use them inside to pass into the hook generated by createApi

Comment: @LoyalPotato that pretty much sounds like a completely new question - but try not to find the perfect type but just a type matching whatever you actually want to call it with in the end?