# How to type a wrapper function in RTK Query?

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I was looking into how I could have the return type be different based on the query args passed into the hook.
I stumbled into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71537035/6251097) answer and it suggested adding a wrapper function and deciding what the return type is ourselves.

I wasn't successful, but this is what I have:

```
// api.ts
export const useGetTQueryWrapper = <RT>(
  args: {
    arg1: string;
    arg2?: string;
  },
  options: {
    skip?: boolean;
    selectFromResult?: (
      result: RTKQueryResult<t1[] | t1>
    ) => RT;
  } = {}
) => {
  const { data, ...rest } = useGetTQuery(args, options);

/*
  I get a ts compile error here:
  Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Pick<QueryActionCreatorResult<QueryDefinition<{ 
  arg1: string; arg2?: string | undefined; }, BaseQueryFn<string | FetchArgs, 
  unknown, FetchBaseQueryError, {}, FetchBaseQueryMeta>, "Tag", 
  t1 | t1[], "reducerPathFoo">>, "refetch">'.ts(2339)
*/

  if (!args.arg2) return { data: data as t1, ...rest };

  return { data: data as t1[], ...rest };
};
```

I have `RT` here so that if I'm using `selectFromResult` the return type is inferred.

`RTKQueryResult` is:

*(I know that error object is missing from this type, I didn't need it for the time being)*

```
export type RTKQueryResult<T> = {
  data?: T;
  isLoading: boolean;
  isFetching: boolean;
  isSuccess: boolean;
  isError: boolean;
};
```

And then I'm using it like so:

```
const {
    selectedData,
    isError
    isFetching,
    isSuccess,
    isError,
  } = useGetTQueryWrapper(
    {
      arg1: "foo",
      arg2: "bar",
    },
    {
      selectFromResult: (result) => {
        return {
          isFetching: result.isFetching,
          isSuccess: result.isSuccess,
          isError: result.isError,
          selectedData: selector(result),
        };
      },
    }
  );
```

`selectedData` here has the inferred type `t1 | t1[]`

Answer (score 0):

Well, your `RT` type does not guarantee that it contains `data` in any way, so you would have to include that.

```js
export const useGetTQueryWrapper = <RT extends { data: any }>(
```

Comment: That fixed the compile error, but the return type is still not showing what I was looking for. If I use a selector that returns a `string[]` it still shows that it returns `t1|t1[]`

Comment: I think the easiest way here would be to write just multiple function signatures with better descriptions of what output for what input you expect.